# FatalErrorException in 44abda604f695ce08bdffef46fad63d0 line 28: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to laravel 5 and making simple wep app for login and registering forum.

But when I use

```
 return View::make('users.new')->with('title', 'Make it snappy Q&A - Register');
```

i get this fatal error

> FatalErrorException in 44abda604f695ce08bdffef46fad63d0 line 28:
>           syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';'giving me headache for long time and couldnot resolve.

Here is my User controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use View;

class User extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
     public $restful = true;

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('users.new')->with('title', 'Make it snappy Q&A - Register');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $validation = User::validate(Input::all());

        if($validation->passes()){
            User::create(array(
                'username'=>Input::get('username'),
                'password'=>Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
                ));
             return Redirect::to_route('home')->with('message','Thanks for registering!');
        } else{
            return Redirect::to_route('register')->with_errors($validation)->with_input();
        }

    }
```

Here is my layout page new.blade.php:

```
    @extends('layout.default')

    @section('content')
    <h1>Register</h1>
    @if($errors->has())
    <p>The following error has occured:</p>
    <ul id ="form-errors">
       {{ $errors->first('username','<li>:message</li>') }}
       {{ $errors->first('password','<li>:message</li>') }}
       {{ $errors->first('password_confirmation','<li>:message</li>') }}
    </ul>
    @endif
    {!! Form::open('register','POST') !!}
    <P>
        {{ Form::label('username','Username:') }}<br />
        {{ Form::text('username',Input::old('username')) }}
    </P>
    <P>
        {{ Form::label('password','Password:') }}<br />
        {{ Form::password('password') }}
    </P>
    <P>
        {{ Form::label('password_confirmation','Confirm password:') }}<br />
        {{ Form::password('password_confirmation')) }}
    </P>

    <p>{{ Form::submit('Register') }}</p>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
    @endsection
```

Comment: Please, at least, fix the formatting of your code, it's totally messed up.

Comment: actually i am new to laravel . Is there any mistake in code.

Comment: There is `here is my new.blade'enter code here'` in the middle of you snippet

Comment: oh sry actually it is new.blade.php layout .it was mistakenly posted but i couldnt figure out the mistake in that blade.Could you sort out ??

Comment: ok sry i did change my snippet

Comment: I can't see the error. You're sure this is the correct file / line ? what is `44abda604f695ce08bdffef46fad63d0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
{{ Form::password('password_confirmation')) }}
```

There is an extra `)`, it should be

```
{{ Form::password('password_confirmation') }}
```

Comment: no problem @anandshrestha57. If you press the "tick" button next to the answer, you can accept this as the answer to your question.